# Blender was closing when i use Subdivision surface»

Tags: subdivision-surface

Description of my problem: I'm modeling/sculpting and when I need to use the "Subdivision surface" modifier I try to use it but when I click on the button that adds this modifier the blender freezes for 1 mi second and closes. How can I solve this problem?
P.s I have a laptop but it pulls a blender and other functions are added without problems.
Pp.s blender version: 3.1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

One issue might that be your system specifications are not enough to handle the process. Try downloading a lower version of blender that is compatible with your system.
By the way, what are your laptop specifications?

Comment: Specifications of my laptop:
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4800MQ CPU @2.70GHz 2.70 GHz
RAM: 16.0 GB
System type: 64-bit operating system x64 processor

Comment: What subdivision level are you trying to apply?

Comment: Do not understand ur question.